# How to use twitter account in iOS9 simulator, Xcode7.2

Tags: ios, twitter, ios-simulator, account

I want to use my twitter account in my iOS simulator of Xcode 7.2, but in the preference app, there's no tab for putting my account in. This is the capture of the screen of the simulator preference app.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWub1.png]

The app I made asked me to allow it to use my twitter account and I allowed it, but error occurred which I've made that means twitter account is not set.

Answer (score 0):

**If you swipe up (click and drag up on the list), you'll find the option beneath Game Center.**

The scroll bar on the right hand side of the simulator is confusing here, as it's unrelated to the Settings scroll view that is shown on screen.